# refl in agda : explaining congruence property

Tags: equality, agda

With the following definition of equality, we have refl as constructor

```
data _≡_ {a} {A : Set a} (x : A) : A → Set a where
    refl : x ≡ x
```

and we can prove that function are congruent on equality

```
cong : ∀ { a b} { A : Set a }  { B : Set b }
       (f : A → B ) {m  n}  → m ≡ n → f m ≡ f n
cong f  refl  = refl
```

I am not sure I can parse what is going on exactly here.
I think we are pattern matching refl on hidden parameters : if we replace the first occurence by refl by another identifier, we get a type error.
after pattern matching, I imagine that m and n are the same by the definition of refl. then magic occurs (a definition of functionality of a relation is applied ? or is it build in ?)

Is there an intuitive description on what is going on ?

Comment: You are pattern matching on `m ≡ n`. `refl` is the only constructor for the type `_≡_` and it only matches syntactically equal expressions, i.e., the two expressions need to represent exactly the same syntax tree. From that it follows that the application of `f` also yields the same syntax tree.

Comment: same syntax tree in the sense that it can be normalized to the same one ? could you add this as an answer so that I can mark it as such

Comment: some related explanation at '9 : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eVTc0zaS_hk&index=3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the arguments in curly braces `{}` are implicit and they only need to be supplied or matched if agda cannot figure them out. It is necessary to specify them, since dependent types needs to refer to the values they depend on, but dragging them around all the time would make the code rather clunky.

The expression `cong f  refl  = refl` matches the explicit arguments (`A → B`) and (`m ≡ n`). If you wanted to match the implicit arguments, you'd need to put the matching expression in `{}`, but here there is no need for that. Then on the right hand side it is indeed the construction of (`f m ≡ f n`) using `refl`, and it works "by magic". Agda has a built-in axiom that proves this to be true. That axiom is similar (but stronger than) `J`-axiom - the induction axiom: if something `C : (x y : A) → (x ≡ y) → Set` is true for `C x x refl`, then it is also true for any `x y : A` and `p : x ≡ y`.

```
J : forall {A : Set} {C : (x y : A) → (x ≡ y) → Set} →
                     (c : ∀ x → C x x refl) →
                     (x y : A) → (p : x ≡ y) → C x y p
-- this really is an axiom, but in Agda there is a stronger built-in,
-- which can be used to prove this
J c x .x refl = c x -- this _looks_ to only mean x ≡ x
                    -- but Agda's built-in extends this proof to all cases
                    -- for which x ≡ y can be constructed - that's the point
                    -- of having induction

cong : ∀ { a b} { A : Set a }  { B : Set b }
       (f : A → B ) {m  n}  → m ≡ n → f m ≡ f n
cong f {x} {y} p = J {C = \x y p → f x ≡ f y} -- the type of equality
                                               -- of function results
                     (\_ → refl) -- f x ≡ f x is true indeed
                     x y p
```

(In this last line we: match explicit arguments `f` and `p`, and also the implicit arguments `m=x` and `n=y`. Then we pass to `J` one implicit argument, but it is not the first positional implicit, so we tell agda that it is `C` in the definition - without doing that, Agda won't see what type is meant by `refl` in `\_ → refl`)

Comment: how very informative, exactly what I need. thank you !